# python networkx digraph efficiency with million of strings

Tags: python, string, networkx, hierarchy, nested-lists

I have a txt with millions of stringlines in it, each similar to this format:

```
#2851= TITLE('object','attribute',#2847,#2848,#2849,#2850);
```

I map a Directional Graph of it with networkx, to get all the nodes and edges, using:

```
def Digraph_path(txt):
  G=nx.DiGraph()
  for l in txt:
    res = re.findall("#\d{3,10}",l)
    for num in res[1:]:
        G.add_edge(res[0],num)
  return G
```

Due to the amount of lines in the txt, the process below takes A LOT of time. I want to make it more efficient. A helpful explanation of the process is that first I have the `obj` items, that each has a list of "parents" related to it, therefore I use `predecessors` first, and extend our `object_num_sets`.

The nature of the information structure in the txt requires us to do this.

After this, I find the children and grandchildren and so on, down to a hierarchy that is,

> genA-->genB-->genC-->genD-->genE-->genF

each time extending my array with those numbers, so in the end each `obj` item in the array is in a nested list with ALL of it's "family" from the txt.

```
 for obj in matrix:
    idx = matrix.index(obj)

    for num in obj:
      object_num_sets[idx].append(num)
      genA = list( Digraph.predecessors(num) )
      object_num_sets[idx].extend(genA)

      for child in genA:
        genB = list( Digraph.successors(child) ) #we find further children

      #our initial obj number has parents, and they have children among 
      #which is also obj itself, so obj has "cousins", but we do not want to
      #repeat obj twice in the same list so we find it and remove it:
        for obj in matrix:
          if obj[0] in genB:
            genB.remove(obj[0]) #remove duplicate #'s
        object_num_sets[idx].extend(genB)

        for childB in genB:
          genC = list( Digraph.successors(childB) )
          object_num_sets[idx].extend(genC)

          for childC in genC:
            gen = list( Digraph.successors(childC) )
            object_num_sets[idx].extend(bnei_ninim)

            for childD in genD:
              genE = list( Digraph.successors(childD) )
              object_num_sets[idx].extend(genE)

              for childE in genE:
                genF = list( Digraph.successors(childE) )
                object_num_sets[idx].extend(genF)
```

The issues are:

1. how can we use `networkx` here more efficiently, given that we do not want to repeat any numbers, but we also do not want to use only `successors`, because we have one instance where we want to find the 'cousins' and therefore we use `predecessors` first... so it's not a simple matter of 'every branch down the tree'
2. can we use `yield` instead of `return` in some way to make the process quicker?
3. What is the difference between using lists vs. generators here? From what I can tell the generators don't do exactly the same things because after each loop they stop existing partially or fully, depending on the nested loop level...?

Comment: (1,2) Neither `yield` nor generators make processing faster. I fact, generators are in general slower than lists.

Comment: @DyZ so do you think it can be made more efficient somehow in a different way?